# Compute $P(9) - Q(10)$ given some equalities of values of $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Let $P(X)$ and $Q(x)$ be cubic polynomials such that

i.) $P(1) = Q(2)$
ii.) $P(3) = Q(4)$
iii.) $P(5) = Q(6)$
iv.) $P(7) = Q(8) + 13$

Compute $P(9) - Q(10)$.

I wanted to set $R(x) = P(x) - Q(x+1) = (x-1)(x-3)(x-5)$, but  I don't think that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almpost there

set  $$R(x)=P(x)-Q(x+1)=a(x-1)(x-3)(x-5)$$ where $a$ is a constant

now use $P(7)-P(8)=13$ to find $a$ and then $R(9)$ should be easy to find

Comment: Why do you need the $a$?

Comment: @EdmundChang since R(x) is a cubic the leading coefficient need not be 1

Comment: Oh... of course